# SQL : Match IN operator with anything

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to build a dynamic query.

This works fine :

```
$qstring="10000, 10001, 10003, 10005";

SELECT *
FROM orders
WHERE order_id in ($qstring);
```

This also works fine when I have no data to match and select.

```
$qstring="";

SELECT *
FROM orders
WHERE order_id in ($qstring);
```

Does something like below exists to match any data? I checked out the pattern matching for SQL but found nothing that could match everything.

```
$qstring="*";

SELECT *
FROM orders
WHERE order_id in ($qstring);
```

Any hints? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to match everything just use the select without the where clause.

```
SELECT * FROM orders
```

If you're forced (for some odd reason to use the construct you described) then...

```
$qstring="SELECT order_id FROM orders";
```

Answer (score 3):

So, you need to make your query:

```
SELECT *
FROM orders
WHERE order_id in ($qstring);
```

Works fine in case there was no values passed in the `@qstring` parameter. In this case try this instead:

```
SELECT * FROM orders 
WHERE ($qstring <> '*' AND order_id in ($qstring));
```

Comment: '$qstring' <> '*', or the SQL won't run, this is PHP the variable is just being inserted into the TSQL string right ?

Answer (score 1):

In case you need everything you should not have a WHERE IN clause.

Check your `$qstring` variable and only append the `WHERE order_id in ($qstring);` when neccessary

Comment: I know that... but that's exactly the problem with building dynamic query. I have the control of $qstring but not of the query statement.